# Return php for-each output as an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

For given foreach loop output is display using echo

```php
$output = array();
$counts = array('45','55','75','95');

foreach ($counts as $count) {
    $output= $count + 10 ;
    echo $output
}
```

it gives

```
output : 556585105
```

But instead of printing this I want to store `$output` as an array variable.

where I want to get `$output = array('55','65', '85', '105');` So later I can grab any value from `$output` using key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify original array like:

```
$counts = array('45','55','75','95');
foreach ($counts as &$count) {
    $count += 10;
}
print_r($counts);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/82771)</kbd>

Comment: Your answer is helpful for array with integer values performing some mathematical operation, But how to deal with the array with strings. I want to return output as array variable instead of printing it.

Comment: @galexy: same method can be applied on string, you only need `.=` instead of `+=`, like [this demo](https://eval.in/82779).

Comment: @SamV: ofc `array_walk` [can also be used](https://eval.in/82783), but for beginners, basic `foreach` is nicer example.

Comment: I am the beginner in php things , I want to know is there any way to store my output as array instead of printing it? I used return but it breaks the operation.

Comment: @galexy: `$counts` is already array. If this code is in function/method, you can return it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the assignment. What you are doing is overwriting the $output. So $output contains the last assignment.

```
$output = array();
$counts = array('45','55','75','95');

foreach ($counts as $count) {

    $output[] = $count + 10 ; // change this        
}
```

Comment: I used addition of integer just for an example ; My question is to stored output as array variable rather than printing each value.

Comment: @galexy Here $output stores one element at a time in foreach. So whatever you store in $output array, will be retrievable later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php

$output = array();
$counts = array('45','55','75','95');

foreach ($counts as $count) {   
    $output[] = $count + 10 ;
    print_r($output);
}
?>
```

Your error was that you did `$output =` when you had to do `$output[] =` . Also remember you can't `echo` variables like that, but you can use `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: Instead of printing each value using print_r or var_dump, I want to stored it as an array variable . Addition of integer is just for an example purpose.

Comment: Yes. They are being stored in the $output variable. print_r was just to show you the way it looked

Comment: thanks @raygo,  I got it! its stored before get print.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
   $array = array();
   $counts = array('45','55','75','95');

   foreach ($counts as $count) {
        $array[] = $count + 10 ;        
   }
   print_r($array); // here is your array
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this array_push() function

```
<?php
$output = array();
$counts = array('45','55','75','95');
foreach ($counts as $count) {
array_push($output,$count + 10 );
}
print_r($output);
?>
```

array_push() function is a built-in function of php